# Solr boost query with additive boost with edismax

Tags: solr, ranking, edismax

Is it possible to specify an additive boost for a set of documents (given a set of document ids) at query time for the extended dismax handler?

I was planning to use bq with an OR'ed list of ids but apparently bq's boost is not additive.

Answer (score 0):

I think query elevation may help :`http://wiki.apache.org/solr/QueryElevationComponent`

Look into :
forceElevation

By default, this component respects the requested 'sort' parameter -- that is, if the request asks to sort by date, it will order the results by date. If forceElevation=true, results will first return the boosted docs, then order by date.

Have elevate.xml

```
<elevate>

 <query text="AAA">
  <doc id="A" />
  <doc id="B" />
 </query>

 <query text="ipod">
  <doc id="A" />

  <!-- you can optionally exclude documents from a query result -->
  <doc id="B" exclude="true" />
 </query>

</elevate>
```

Comment: This doesn't change the score and affects sorting directly bypassing the score, right? Also as far as I understand it doesn't allow specifying the list of doc ids at request time, only a pre-configured one.

Comment: Yes. Please play with it and let you know what you find.